# What would be the easiest way to make my meter represent the number in the centre?

Tags: javascript, html, css

270 degree meter with number in the centre to represent the bar

[image]

Hi, I would like to make my bar around the outside represent the number in the middle - so when it is 0, the bar is entirely white (the colour underneath) it, and when it is 100 it looks as shown above. I have the image as a photoshop file and I am trying to represent it in html/css.

I have tried using the radial-gradient attribute, but struggled to get any of it to work. Here is the code I was using:

```css
#BlueBoostMeter{
    position: absolute;
    width: 141px;
    height: 141px;
    top: 882px;
    left: 1761px;
}

#BlueBoostMeter::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, #4CAF50 0%, #4CAF50 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#BlueBoostMeter::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(calc(120deg - 90deg));
    transform-origin: center;

}
```

```html
<img id="BlueBoostMeter" src="ModularPieces/BlueBoostMeter.png">
```

all help is appreciated :)

Comment: img is replacement element. If image loaded sucessfully, then pseudo element remove.

Comment: Start by not moving the image off the screen like now

Comment: Please show more images. For example, what does it look like with a value of 0, a value of 40, and a value of 100.